# Asp.Net Core 3.x - How to change the Linq expression to include search in a List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code for a search functionality:

```
productsData = productsData.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchValue)
                                       || m.Ingredients.Any(i => i.Contains(searchValue)));
```

Where `m.Ingredients` is a `List<string>`.

and get this error:

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, > or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

While I understand this is happening because of the breaking change in 3.0 where the query is translated on the server, I don't really know how to change it without adding `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`.

Comment: If you want the 2.x behavior (evaluation on the client, i.e. not in the database), then you an just add a `AsEnumerable()`. Otherwise, you will need to change the query in a way that it can actually run in the database.

Comment: It may give a  IQueryable<> or Enumerable, you need to use ToList() if you're trying to access productsData values. If you're trying to avoid these functions, loop through  your dataset to create a new filtered list. But it will end up with the same outcome (even worse)